# Need to find PageRank answer for an upcoming exam

Tags: pagerank

Hi as apart of an exam we need to answer the following question:
Write the PageRank technique as a series of steps.

Can someone help me answer this because online I can't find simple answers related to this but all are long and very scientific.  Was just looking for a few simple steps in simple English how PageRank works.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about running your website.

Comment: Pagerank is a technical topic that cannot be simplified too much. Keep researching. This is real work. You will not find your homework done for you. I suggest using Wikipedia to lookup Pagerank and read the linked citations at the bottom. There are some that explain the concept reasonably well. Also, some of the better SEO sites may be able to help. Cheers!!